# Type not being translated while using ajv-i18n

Tags: internationalization, ajv, react-jsonschema-forms

I want to translate the errors of my schema automatically using `ajv-i18n`. However the error is not translated completely (the type is displayed as "number" (english) instead of "número" (spanish)). This is the code Im using (you can check the [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-2tfqyf?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A5%2C1)):

```js
import RjsfCoreForm from "@rjsf/core";
import { customizeValidator } from "@rjsf/validator-ajv8";
import spanishLocalizer from "ajv-i18n/localize/es";

const validator = customizeValidator({}, spanishLocalizer);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RjsfCoreForm schema={schema} validator={validator} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The result containing the untranslated word "number":

[image]

- [Github issue](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-i18n/issues/54)